# How to dynamically include values in checkbox using JSP?

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I created one table. Values in it will be dynamically created from the database. I add a checkbox at the last column. Now what I like to know is that, when the checkbox is selected that particular row alone want to be stored in new database, so according to how much checkbox is selected that much row should be added in the database. Can any one help me with this?
Thanks in advance...

My code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%
    String connectionURL = "";
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int f=0;
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>csepoff</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="cse" action="csepoffcheck1.jsp">
        <%
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","tajmahalss");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String[] batchcse=request.getParameterValues("batchcse");
            String batchhcse="";
            String data="";
            String data1="";
            String data2="";

            for(int i=0; i<batchcse.length; i++) {
                batchhcse+=batchcse[i]+" ";
            }

            rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from signup where batch='"+batchhcse+"'");

            out.println("<table border='1'><tr>");
            out.println("<th>NAME</th><th>DEPARTMENT</th><th>BATCH</th>");
            out.println("<th>FATHER NAME</th><th>MOTHER NAME</th><th>SELECT</th>");

            while(rs.next()){
                out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("name")+"</td>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("depart")+"</td>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("batch")+"</td>");
                out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("fname")+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("mname")+"</td>");
                out.println("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" value=\"${}\"></td>");
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");
        %>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing, do not write java code in JSP at all. JSPs are meant for representation only. 
Still as answer to this question you can follow this.

You can set the value of checkbox as `rs.getString("id")` where `id` is the primary key of the row in the table.

After you submit the form you can retrieve che checkbox values as

```
String[] cbValues =  request.getParameterValues("checkBoxNameAsInHtmlForm");
```

and using its `cbValues.length`, you can know how many records need to be created in the database.

Also instead of writing `out.println()` statements, you should write.

```
<form name="cse" action="csepoffcheck1.jsp">
        <table border='1'>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>Select</th>
            <%
                while (rs.next()) {
            %>
            <td><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
                value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>"></td>

            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>

    </form>
```

Well this is not also the good way because it breaks the purpose of MVC architecture.Just for current situation, do this.

Next time follow the MVC pattern and do not write java code in jsp at all. Its a very bad thing.